# Removing indent in PYDEV

Tags: python, pydev

I am using pydev for python development. I am facing issue while removing indentation for a block of statement.

If I have to add indentation I used to press **SHIFT + down** arrow key until I reach the end of block of statements which I want to indent and then press the TAB key.This is how i used to add indent for a block of statements in one step.

The issue now I am facing is to remove indent in one step for a block of statement.For example I have a for loop and i have a block of statement with in that for loop. Now I dont want to have the for loop any more and want to remove the indent underlying the for loop  statement block. At present I am going each line and press backspace to remove that indentation. Is there any easy way to do this for the entire statement block?

Comment: Not sure if it works in PyDev but in other editors SHIFT + TAB will unindent one tab. Have you tried highlighting your section and holding SHIFT then pressing TAB?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know Pydev, but in most editors Shift+Tab will do the trick.

Comment: Hi Thanks for ur reply,As mentioned in my above post I am using SHIFT+TAB to add intend. My issue is to remove the intend.

Comment: @techrawther: In your post you say you use SHIFT+Down Arrow to highlight the text, then you say you press the TAB key. Are you saying you're still holding SHIFT when you press the TAB key?

Comment: Yes, by Shift+Tab I meant holding Shift while pressing Tab.

Comment: while pressing the TAB key SHIFT key was not held.After reading u r comment I tried SHIFT + TAB together and it worked Now I am able to remove those indent in one step. Thanks alot guys

Comment: @PetrViktorin - You dont know pydev, but you are correct sir :-)

Comment: @techrawther, if this helped you, please click the ✓ to the left to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

From pydev.org, their page:

Block indent (and dedent)   Tab / Shift-Tab

Smart indent (and dedent)   Enter / Backspace